# Colorbox Iframe height is wrong in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox, colorbox

It seems Chrome and Firefox handle the height of my embed youtube video differently.
While chrome do it right:

```
$(".youtube-video").colorbox({
  iframe:true,
  width: '33%',
  height: '33%'
});
```

Firefox not using 33% of the screens height. It uses less (like only 10%). I guess the problem has something to do with loaded content height of the iframe. But i have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: tried innerHeight and some onComplete functions with no positive result :(

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me and others.  If you can create a reproducible demo of the problem, submit it to colorbox's issue list on github.  I imagine when you try to simplify the problem to create the demo, you'll find the real issue (user error, unrelated conflicting script, what have you).